# C# to Convert String to DateTime

Tags: c#

How to convert the below string to `DateTime` in C#?

```
Mon Apr 22 07:56:21 +0000 2013
```

When i tried the code with

```
Convert.ToDateTime("Mon Apr 22 07:56:21 +0000 2013")
```

it is throwing error as

> *String was not considered as valid DateTime*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `DateTime.ParseExact` instead.

Example:

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
dateString = "Sun 15 Jun 2008 8:30 AM -06:00";
format = "ddd dd MMM yyyy h:mm tt zzz";
result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
```

More examples are available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify that your input string is in a particular format. Please refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) link and this [one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc165448.aspx) too.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact` like:

```
string str = "Mon Apr 22 07:56:21 +0000 2013";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str,
                                   "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss +0000 yyyy",
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have basically two options for this. 
[DateTime.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) and [DateTime.ParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx). like

```
DateTime parseexactdt = DateTime.ParseExact("Mon Apr 22 07:56:21 +0000 2013",
                                   "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss +0000 yyyy",
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string input = "Mon Apr 22 07:56:21 +0000 2013";
string format = "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss +ffff yyyy";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(input,format,  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            DateTimeStyles.None,out dt))
{
    // do something with dt
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CultureInfo cult = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

            string txt = "Mon Apr 22 07:56:21 +0000 2013";
            string format = "ddd MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy";
            DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(txt, format, cult);

        }
    }
}
```

If you run program from country with +06:00, you get time 13:56:21 with same date