# convert string unique date output to type date-time in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I am extracting the data from an api and I am getting this value `"Fri Aug 16 21:06:52 +0000 2013"` I would like to know how I would be able to change this string value to type Date time

Comment: It's called parsing, try googling it. `DateTime.Parse` or `TryParse` or `TryParseExact` could be usefull.

Comment: There was many posts about it.
see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978359/c-sharp-to-convert-string-to-datetime/16978561#16978561

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx)

```
DateTime.ParseExact("Aug 16 21:06:52 +0000 2013", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss +ffff yyyy", 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: `"ffff"` is for fractional seconds, but in his string the time zone is given. So technically `"ffff"` is wrong (though it works).

Answer (score 1):

You should read [DateTime custom formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

this should solve your problem thougf it

```
 DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact("Aug 16 21:06:52 +0000 2013", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or to do it more appropriately and avoid exceptions. Do it like this

```
//zzz is Hours and minutes offset from UTC
string[] formats = { "MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy" }; 
DateTime result;
string date = "Aug 16 21:06:52 +0000 2013";
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, formats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
{
    // i prefer this method though
}
```

Comment: _"ffff" is for fractional seconds, but in his string the time zone is given. So technically "ffff" is wrong (though it works)_ (copied from Jeppe's comment on [Adil's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18311573/284240)).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782365.aspx) or (if the input may be invalid) [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/h9b85w22.aspx):

```
string input = "Aug 16 21:06:52 +0000 2013";
DateTime output;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out output))
{ 
    // date was parsable, here is it:
    Console.WriteLine(output.ToLongDateString());
}
```

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx), especially the ["zzz" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#zzzSpecifier)

Answer (score 0):

Parsing string to datetime:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx
DateTime.TryParse() returns true or false for success / fail. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx
DateTime.Parse() throws an exception on failure.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways...

[DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx)

```
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParse("Aug 16 21:06:52 +0000 2013", out dt))
{
     //parsing was successfull
}
```

This won't throw an exception if the parse fails.

Then there is [DateTime.Parse:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx)

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("Aug 16 21:06:52 +0000 2013");
```

Unlike `TryParse`, this will throw an exception if parsing fails.

And there is also, [Convert.ToDateTime:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todatetime.aspx)

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("Aug 16 21:06:52 +0000 2013", culture);
```

This also throws an error if the conversion fails.

Answer (score 0):

Edited after you updated your question.

If you want it converted to your local time zone, use:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("Fri Aug 16 21:06:52 +0000 2013",
  "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy",
  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Otherwise, use:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("Fri Aug 16 21:06:52 +0000 2013",
  "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy",
  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
  DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

If the `+0000` is always like that in the input, and you want to disregard that completely, use:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("Fri Aug 16 21:06:52 +0000 2013",
  "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss +0000 yyyy",
  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```