# Convert string to DateTime and format

Tags: c#, datetime

Can i convert the string below to `DateTime`

Friday, 27th September 2013

This is what i want to achieve:

```
String tmpDate="Friday, 27th September 2013";
closingDate = Convert.ToDateTime(tmpDate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Doing above i get error:

> *The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown
>   word starting at index 10.*

Comment: Are you getting an error? What about this is not working?

Comment: @RyanHenderson i am getting error updated in quesitons.

Comment: see this link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978359/c-sharp-to-convert-string-to-datetime

Comment: @V4Vendetta i did same error , i am assuming it because of th with 27.

Comment: @confusedMind It is because of "th", check my answer.

Comment: @Andrew so i have to replace th,nd,st rite?

Comment: I guess this issue is same as yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583285/clever-way-to-parse-dates-c-sharp

Comment: @V4Vendetta exactly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure there is exactly solution with `-th, -st, -nd`, but you can use this like;

```
string tmpDate = "Friday, 27 September 2013";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(tmpDate,
                                  "dddd, dd MMMM yyyy",
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Here a [**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/Mu70Sm).

I almost suggest you remove `-th`, `-st` and `-nd` part of your string but these are break the rules `:)`

- August
- Monday
- Thursday
- Sunday

Also check *[Habib's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14583296/447156)* which seems nice.

Comment: Thanx a lot but i have to choose the one that answered first and correct as that is fair . Thank you once again.

Comment: @confusedMind: Always choose the _best_ answer, if there are multiple same choose the first. SO honours the fastest already with upvotes. Quality should win finally.

Answer (score 2):

You can maintain the ordinals to remove in an array like this (which might make it easier to add/remove ordinals from other languages). That way you don't have to manually remove the ordinal from each string input. Using `TryParseExact` avoids an exception being thrown if the `DateTime` could not be parsed from the string.

```
String tmpDate = "Friday, 27th September 2013";
string[] split = tmpDate.Split();
string[] ordinals = new string[] { "th", "nd", "st" };

foreach (string ord in ordinals)
   split[1] = split[1].Replace(ord, "");

tmpDate = String.Join(" ", split);
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(tmpDate, "dddd, dd MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
   Console.WriteLine("Parsed");
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("Could not parse");
}
```

Comment: but if month is `August` is this will replace it as `Augu`?

Comment: No because split[1] should always be the numerical date, not the month, if the format is consistent. If the format changes then the `TryParseExact` would fail anyway so that would be a different issue.

Comment: But your solution can't parse `Friday, 27th August 2013` ?

Comment: @SonerGönül - `Friday, 27th August 2013` is not a valid date. `27th August 2013` was a `Tuesday`. Your answer would (haven't tested) throw an exception if you tried to parse `Friday, 27th August 2013`.

Comment: Looks like doesn't matter. It can't parse `Tuesday, 27th August 2013` either. In my opinion, the real answer of this question should be like; `there is no direct parsing dates formated like that bro :)`

Comment: I just tried it and it parsed for me. My answer isn't any different from yours except that mine automatically removes `th`, `st`, and `nd`. If you put a breakpoint just before the `TryParseExact`, `tmpDate` should match your string. Unless you replace `null` with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`?

Comment: Weird.. Couldn't parse on my machine, but could parse in Ideone http://ideone.com/2UUMMu I think this is happening because of .net framework version. On my machine, I had the older one.. Looks like you are right `;)`

Comment: Might be Culture related, possibly? I'll update the answer to use `InvariantCulture`.

Comment: Yeah, When I try to parse, I fail first time on every time :D

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is in the exception you are getting. Obviously, "th" is not needed here. Just remove it and you are good to go.

This is working perfectly fine for me

```
String tmpDate = "Friday, 27 September 2013";
closingDate = Convert.ToDateTime(tmpDate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 0):

you will have to remove the th, nd,rd and st manually, as there isn't any format that takes these into account. After that you can use try parse exact like below

```
String tmpDate = "Friday, 27th September 2013";
tmpDate = tmpDate.Replace("nd", "")
            .Replace("th", "")
            .Replace("rd", "")
            .Replace("st", "");            
string[] formats = { "dddd, dd MMMM yyyy" };
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(tmpDate, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, out dt))
{
     //parsing is successful
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the format of the date string you provide does not change, the -st, -nd and -th can easily be removed (as already suggested).

Also be sure to provide a valid (existing) date, or a System.FormatException will be thrown.

```
string tmpDate = "Friday, 27th September 2013";

string[] splitDate = tmpDate.Split(new Char[] {' '});
splitDate[1] = splitDate[1].Substring(0, splitDate[1].Length-2);
string tmpDatewithoutStNdTh = String.Join(" ", splitDate);

try{
    string closingDate = Convert.ToDateTime(tmpDatewithoutStNdTh).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Console.WriteLine(closingDate.ToString());
}
catch(System.FormatException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The provided date does not exist.");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

See  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse.aspx

```
public class Example
{
public static void Main()
{
  string[] dateStrings = {"2008-05-01T07:34:42-5:00", 
                          "2008-05-01 7:34:42Z", 
                          "Thu, 01 May 2008 07:34:42 GMT"};
  foreach (string dateString in dateStrings)
  {
     DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
     Console.WriteLine("Converted {0} to {1} time {2}", 
                       dateString, 
                       convertedDate.Kind.ToString(), 
                       convertedDate);
  }                              
}
}
```

Comment: not working for me becase of the th i assume, so i have to remove that , (th,st,nd)